# How do you create a user and role at the same time?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to create a user and assign it a role at the same time. How do you do this since ApplicationUser doesnt have the tables needed and running it separate in an ApplicationRole or by itself pops it for a null NormalizedRoleName, even when you actually set the normalizeRoleName

```
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateUser(UserInfo user)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                ApplicationUser appUser = new ApplicationUser
                {
                    UserName = user.Email,
                    FirstName = user.FirstName,
                    LastName = user.LastName,
                    Email = user.Email,  
                    
                };
                IdentityResult result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(appUser, user.Password);


                if (result.Succeeded)


                {
                    ApplicationRole role = new ApplicationRole
                    {
                        RoleName = user.RoleName,
                        NormalizedRoleName = user.RoleName.ToUpper()
                    };

                 IdentityResult roleresult = await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(appUser, role.RoleName);
               
            


                if (roleresult.Succeeded)
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                else
                {
                    foreach (IdentityError error in result.Errors)
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", error.Description);
                }
                }
            }


            return View(user);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to register user and role at the same time, you can create a ViewModel whitch contains user's attributes and role's attributes, Then use this ViewModel to pass the date from view to controller.

**Here is a simple Demo**

*ViewModel*

```
public class Register
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        
        public string Password { get; set; }

        public string Rolename  { get; set; }
    }
```

*View*

```
@model CustomIdentity.Models.Register

<form asp-controller="Test" asp-action="Register" method="post"> 
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="@Model.UserName"></label>
        <input asp-for="@Model.UserName" />
    </div>
   
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="@Model.Password"></label>
        <input asp-for="@Model.Password" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="@Model.Rolename"></label>
        <input asp-for="@Model.Rolename" />
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

*controller*

```
     //Inject UserManager and RoleManager into the controller
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Register(Register model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new IdentityUser { ClassName = model.ClassName};
                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    var role = new IdentityRole { Name = model.Rolename };
                    var result1 = await _roleManager.CreateAsync(role);
                    if (result1.Succeeded)
                    {
//make sure the user and role register successfully, then we can use `AddToRoleAsync` to add the relationship between them
                        await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, role.Name);
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                    }
                }
            }

            return View(model);
        }
```

**Then you can create a user and assign it a role at the same time**